# Wide range Ohmic region Mosfet

Tags: mosfet, electrical, specifications

I would like to have a N- Channel (Enhancement mode) MOSFET with wide range of Ohmic region for my project. It's like Vgs varies from 1V to 5V (Ohmic region), Vgs threshold should be >5V, Ids continuous current should be around 5A. 
Type : Through hole. Can you please suggest any MOSFET which is suitable with above spec ?

Explanation : What exactly i need is :

[image]

I'm going to use this MOSFET as Low side switch to control the load current. So, I'm controlling the Vgs from (0-5V), While Ids continuous current 5A (max. operating current) Which means

When Vgs- 0V Ids - 0A,
     Vgs- 5V Ids - 5A,   This should be operate in ohmic region.

```
Vds is 24V.
```

Note : 
1. Don't consider the R7 (i'm not using it) mentioned in image.

2. For schematic purpose i just using the Mosfet IRF2804. (Doesn't mean that i'm using this mosfet)

Comment: When \$V_{GS,th}\$ > 5V, it will be in cutoff mode for \$V_{GS}\$ < 5V, so, apart from product recommendations being off-topic on this site, you should redefine your specs.

Comment: Basically all MOSFETs that you can buy are intended for **switching applications** meaning that they will have a **low** resistance when on and a **high** resistance when off. The region between that low and high isn't well defined and also **unusable** as the on/off switching (controlled by \$V_{GS}\$ is quite abrupt. You cannot expect that a MOSFET (**any** MOSFET) will have a certain resistance was long as you apply a certain \$V_{GS}\$. That's simply not how MOSFETs work. So: the MOSFET you want simply **does not exist**.

Comment: Could you accept a circuit which works as voltage controlled resistor? What voltage and resistance ranges you expect? DC only or do you need it as bipolar? The frequency range? Should the control be linear? In theory it's possible that you reach some final application which could be realized in a simpler way. I guess it's useful to reveal that ultimate goal.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: You are wrong. The MOSFETs do have a region of changing resistance dependent on the Vgs. You can actually use them as variable resistors, it's just that you can't guarantee the same resistance for the same Vgs value across different resistors.

Comment: 100% definite XY problem. Explain what you are trying to achieve without mentioning the word "MOSFET". Fully explain what the signals are and what power rails you have available.

Comment: @EdinFifić *The MOSFETs do have a region of changing resistance dependent on the Vgs.* Read my comment carefully, I never claimed that MOSFETs do not have that. They do but it is quite unusable, without feedback of some sort it is impossible to predict what the actual resistance will be. But feel free to prove me wrong and show me a circuit where a MOSFET is used as some variable resistor and that circuit does not use feedback to control that MOSFET resistance value.

Comment: @razeen: You need to specify the Vds voltage range that you will be using this MOSFET for.

Answer (score 1):

I can only give you a link to Digi-Key where you can search for any MOSFET you like.
I have already pre-selected only active, in-stock, N-channel, Vgs threshold at 5V@250μA, through hole MOSFETS for you. Just remember that it is better to use a MOSFET with a higher current rating if you expect to be using it at its maximum.
You just have to select the one you like:
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&sf=1&FV=69%7C411897%2C606%7C378999%2C1989%7C0%2C-8%7C278%2C1236%7C249240&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=500

EDIT: Most MOSFETs can be used as variable resistors but in a very limited Vgs and Vds area. You need to use the ohmic region between zero Vgs and their rated turn on Vgs (Vgs threshold).
After searching a little more, I have come across LINEAR series MOSFETs on Digi-Key. They have a wider ohmic region than the ordinary MOSFETs, but are not cheap.
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?k=linear+mosfet&k=&pkeyword=linear+mosfet&sv=0&pv69=411897&sf=1&FV=-8%7C278&quantity=&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&pageSize=500

P.S.: In 1999., my supervisor (an electrical engineer) tasked me with making an adjustable load using a MOSFET, a potentiometer and a 9V battery. He gave me the simple schematic, and if I remember correctly, the circuit worked. We needed simple and cheap DC loads for testing DC-DC converters made with our company's ICs, as the commercial variable loads were expensive (we had programmable electronic loads by HP). The load voltages were mainly up to 5V, so this was doable with a MOSFET. I don't remember which MOSFET model did we use.

Comment: Edin, regarding that would you think its viable to use mosfets in this fashion for rf attenuation? are there any special requirements you can think of? and in the case of discrete mosfets how do you deal with the body diode? i knew this usage was a thing but only on ics as the body isn't necessarily connected directly to the source

Comment: I don't have enough about its use in RF attenuation. As far as I know, FET is used for such attenuation.

Comment: *It irks me when people rush to share their wrong/incorrect knowledge with so much self-confidence and mislead others.* Have you considered that maybe your knowledge isn't entirely correct? Yes MOSFETs do have an ohmic region. That doesn't mean they can be used as a resistor that can be controlled by using \$V_{GS}\$ in a predictable way. But again, prove me wrong by showing a circuit that does just that as I'd like to know how that's done.

Comment: You're right that it can't be done in a predictable way, and that it can be done over a very small range of voltages. There are linear series of MOSFETs that have an expanded ohmic/linear region, but nothing too spectacular. I have updated my answer with more info, will provide a circuit if I get a chance. I apologize for misunderstanding.